# How to write a program that balances the symbols?

Tags: java

I am writing a program for hw. We are supposed to balance these symbols 
`l { }'s, ( )'s, [ ]'s, " "'s, and /* */'s` and ignore string literals and comments blocks, but I don't know how to do that. My code is partially working, but when it comes to `{ }` it can't tell. It also has problems dealing with `/* */`. I'm stuck and don't know which way to go.

For example, given:

```
 public class Test { 
    public static final void main(String[ ) args) { 
        System.out.println("Hello."); 
    } 
}
```

It prints two `}` mismatches because `{` is not immediately before `}`. We are required to push the symbols onto a stack and pop them to compare. We also need to write our own stack method called MyStack.java

I provided the main here:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class SymbolBalance {

    public static void main(String[] args){
           if(args.length>0){
               try{
                   Scanner input = new Scanner(new File (args[0]));
                   MyStack<Character> ms = new MyStack<>();
                   String str;
                   char ch;
                   while(input.hasNext()){
                       str = input.next();
                       for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
                           ch = str.charAt(i);
                           if(ch == '{'||ch =='(' || ch=='[' ||ch=='"'||
                                   (ch == '/'&&i<str.length() -1&&str.charAt(i+1)=='*'))
                           {
                               ms.push(ch);
                           }
                           else if (ch==')'){
                               if(ms.isEmpty()||ms.pop()!= '('){
                                   System.out.println(") is mismatched");
                               }
                           }
                           else if(ch == ']'){
                            if(ms.isEmpty() || ms.pop() != '['){
                                System.out.println("] is mismatched");
                            }
                        }
                           else if(ch == '}'){
                            if(ms.isEmpty() || ms.pop() != '{'){
                                System.out.println("} is mismatched");
                            }
                        }
                           else if(ch == '*' && i<str.length()-1&&str.charAt(i+1) == '/'){
                            if(ms.isEmpty() || ms.pop() != '*'){
                                System.out.println("*/ is mismatched");
                            }
                        }
                           else if(ch == '"'){
                            if(ms.isEmpty() || ms.pop() != '"'){
                               System.out.println(" \"\" is mismateched");
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
                   input.close();
                }
               catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                   System.out.println("Cannot find file");
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }

             }
           else{
               System.out.println("No command line argument");
           }
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please take some time to visit the [help] and also read [ask].  Questions of the form "here's my code, please debug it" are considered off-topic. StackOverflow is not a discussion, tutorial or debugging site. The way this works is you are expected to attempt to solve the problem and then ask for help when you run into a difficulty, explaining clearly what you have tried and what you don't understand. At a minimum you should already have stepped through the code in an IDE debugger and be able to identify results that don't match your expectation.

Comment: Did you try to debug your code? Can you say where or why your programm can't handle '{' correct?

Comment: Please see [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: grammar fixed

code highlighted

Answer (score 0):

Your program is 99% correct. The only part where there is a logical fallacy is on the special case of a double quote.

A double quote is a special symbol in the sense that it is the same symbol to denote both start and end of a quotation. The other symbols in your list have different start and end notations. E.g. a bracket. Start bracket is denoted by '[' and end one is denoted by ']'. However for a double quote, `"` can denote either a start or an end of a quote.

Since a double quote mark is a special symbol, you need to handle it in a special way. When you push or pop a double quote symbol to your `MyStack` stack, you need to keep a track of whether it is a start or an end. There could be many ways to keep a track of it. I would suggest a boolean flag indicating the same. You need to flip the flag every time you push or pop a double quote to your stack.

Following is a working instance of your program with my revisions:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
       if(args.length>0){
           try{
               Scanner input = new Scanner(new File (args[0]));
               MyStack<Character> ms = new MyStack<>();
               String str;
               char ch;
               boolean quoteStart = true; //Flag to indicate quote start or end
               while(input.hasNext()){
                   str = input.next();
                   for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
                       ch = str.charAt(i);
                       //Remove the " from the following condition. Handle it later.
                       if(ch == '{'||ch =='(' || ch=='[' ||
                               (ch == '/'&&i<str.length() -1&&str.charAt(i+1)=='*'))
                       {
                           ms.push(ch);
                       }
                       else if (ch==')'){
                           if(ms.isEmpty()||ms.pop()!= '('){
                               System.out.println(") is mismatched");
                           }
                       }
                       else if(ch == ']'){
                        if(ms.isEmpty() || ms.pop() != '['){
                            System.out.println("] is mismatched");
                        }
                    }
                       else if(ch == '}'){
                        if(ms.isEmpty() || ms.pop() != '{'){
                            System.out.println("} is mismatched");
                        }
                    }
                       else if(ch == '*' && i<str.length()-1&&str.charAt(i+1) == '/'){
                        if(ms.isEmpty() || ms.pop() != '*'){
                            System.out.println("*/ is mismatched");
                        }
                    }
                     //Handle the quote here
                       else if(ch == '"'){
                        if(quoteStart == true) {
                            ms.push(ch);
                            quoteStart = false;
                        }
                        else {
                            if(ms.isEmpty() || ms.pop() != '"'){
                               System.out.println(" \"\" is mismateched");
                            }
                            quoteStart = true;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
               input.close();
            }
           catch(FileNotFoundException e){
               System.out.println("Cannot find file");
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

         }
       else{
           System.out.println("No command line argument");
       }
}
```